# How can I relax SSL requirements inside a specific folder?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-ssl

I have a root folder that is protected by a `SSLRequire` rule; say:

```
SSLRequire %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_Email} =~ m/^.+@foobar\.com$/
```

However, I'd like a subfolder of this root folder to be protected by a completely different one, like this:

```
SSLRequire %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_Email} =~ m/^.+@frobnicate\.com$/
```

So far I've had no luck in changing the rule, access always fail and the logs tell me that a rule didn't match. I get the message even with `SSLRequire true`.